# How to filter events by 2 or more user properties in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

I've integrated my Firebase project with Big query to store Firebase analytics events. I'm using Data Studio to visualize the data. I'm trying to filter events based on user properties. I have 3 user property such as department, username and app_version. I can filter events by using any one of the user property name but I cannot filter events by using 2 or all three user properties. 
For e.g I'm trying to get events from John Cena(username) who's using v1.8(app_version) and belongs to factory(department). But no success, as soon as I select any one of the user property in filter, the user properties disappear in other filters.
Any ideas, Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution. I needed to UNNEST the user properties into seperate columns.
I made a new data source with a custom query something like this:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='app_version').string_value AS app_version,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='userName').string_value as userName,
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='department').string_value as department
FROM `xxxxxxxxxxx.analytics_yyyyyyyyy.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180521' AND '20240131';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the user properties values in the `WHERE` clause, you can do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT *,
            (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key = 'app_version').string_value AS appVersion,
            (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='userName').string_value as userName,
            (SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='department').string_value as department,
        FROM `xxxxxxxxxxx.analytics_yyyyyyyyy.events_*`
        WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20180521' AND '20240131'
    ) AS TOT
WHERE TOT.appVersion = '2.3.0'
AND TOT.userName = 'Example'
AND TOT.department = 'DepA'
```